# Why is "Meet Attendance" icon not enabled in Google Meet?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-add-ons, google-meet

I (seem to) have installed the [Meet Attendance](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meet-attendance/nenibigflkdikhamlnekfppbganmojlg?hl=en) Chrome extension for Google Meet by claycodes.org from Chrome Web store from my Android phone. The site responded by messaging that it has been *added to the desktop*.

But I find that the feature is not enabled when I start Google Meet on my Android phone, because I can not see the *checkbox icon* representing "Meet Attendance" during the Google Meet session.

Can I have this feature enabled so that I can use it on my Android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a desktop to use that extension as it needs the desktop version of Chrome, and attendance will show up only when you join a meeting, given you are using a desktop.

You can still use the Google Meet Android app (which lacks important features from the web) and you can't add features that are not available there.